# Do you know any alternative at Redis list?

Tags: memory, redis, queue, out-of-memory

I've been using Redis as a queue to communicate between distributed python scripts. At any moment, some nodes push and some nodes pop values from a list.

I've run into a problem, however. At a certain point a LPUSH will make the server run out of memmory. As i understand the virtual memmory feature that used to exist in Redis until version 2.4 is considered deprecated (and thus advised against).

The problem i have is that a strategy that discards any key is not acceptable. As such, the server is configured with noeviction (values are not evicted and an error should be returned).

What I would need is a way to find out that the command failed from redis-py so I can make a particular node wait until there is space to push items into the list. I've looked through the code and redis-py itself throws no exceptions (it doesn't use exceptions as a design choice).

LPUSH itself returns the number of records in that particular list, however, since the list is accessed from different nodes, the value itself will tell me nothing.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Please tell me if any additional information on the nature of the problem would help clarify it.

Comment: You want to check if you will run out of memory when you LPUSH (or before)?

Comment: are you poping that list?